Reduce the ring-bell volume in GNU Emacs
Is it possible to reduce the ring-bell volume in Emacs using the configuration file?

I have read in this emackwiki documentation that I was possible in XEmacs using (setq bell-volume 0).
I also found this documentation from GNU Emacs which talks about reducing bell volume in X Window System, but it doesn't look like lisp code.


you can use the config in this answer to disable ring-bell for certain actions

You can also replace the sound with a mild visual indication. E.g. echo-bell.el.

xset is a shell command. You can certainly write a  Lisp function to run it.  The main question is whether it works: try it from a terminal first before you write the function.
